# Surface Pro 5 cannot find bootable drive, trying to install Ubuntu in place of windows 10 os

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, 22.04, disk-formatting

I had successfully downloaded ubuntu in place of microsoft then was blocked from downloading a software packet through the terminal by secure boot. I went to the bios screen and disabled secure boot then was unable to access the ubuntu os. I reinstalled the windows 10 os but not before formatting a 230ish GB partition on the hard drive (250GB laptop). This was the only way I thought to reinstall the windows os. now when I try to boot from usb following the same steps that successfully worked before I get a screen saying could not find bootable device. Is there a fix to this? Microsoft os is currently running fine but I would still like to run a linux os instead.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/wiki/Installation-and-Setup